# Add content before/after admin post wp-list-table

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, wp-list-table

I know there are two hooks to add content before and after a taxonomy wp-list-table.

Is there an action to add content after the post type wp-list-table on the edit.php page?

---

For $taxonomy List Tables:

```
add_action( 'category' . '_pre_add_form', 'copy_above_form' );
function copy_above_form( $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>Above the WP-List-Table</p>';
}

add_action( 'after-' . 'category' . '-table', 'copy_below_table' );
function copy_below_table( $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>Below the WP-List-Table</p>';
}
```

Reference: https://trepmal.com/action_hook/after-category-table/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has probably been solved many times here on this site, but maybe not with all your requirements? So let me try to answer it here:

You can try to use the `all_admin_notices` and `in_admin_footer` actions, wrapped inside the `load-edit.php` action to target the `edit.php` page:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function(){

   $screen = get_current_screen(); 

    // Only edit post screen:
   if( 'edit-post' === $screen->id )
   {
        // Before:
        add_action( 'all_admin_notices', function(){
            echo '<p>Greetings from <strong>all_admin_notices</strong>!</p>';
        });

        // After:
        add_action( 'in_admin_footer', function(){
            echo '<p>Goodbye from <strong>in_admin_footer</strong>!</p>';
        });
    }
});
```

This will render like the following screenshots:

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

You can then easily modify this to target the `edit.php` screen for different custom post types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks birgire, I did notice this was an option - but it was adding onto the admin footer. The other alternative was via a javascript function, but I did not think that was the correct way to do it. Since there are no actions to hook onto the edit-post page, I believe this may only be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did check the `WP_List_Table` class and the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class, but I didn't find any useful hooks there. It would be handy if one could extend these classes and replace the current instances ;-) The instance is created via `$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');` but there's no filter/hook in this internal function `_get_list_table()` see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/list-table.php#L10). The Codex also says: *This is a private, internal WordPress function. It should not be called directly or used by developers.*