# Add content in custom post type page after the title and before columns

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, wp-list-table

I found here on WPSE that you can [add content before post title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140319/add-content-before-after-admin-post-wp-list-table) in the post page, and in custom post type pages

```
    add_action( 'load-edit.php', function(){

       $screen = get_current_screen();

        // Only edit post screen:
       if( 'edit-reservation' === $screen->id )
       {
            // Before:
            add_action( 'all_admin_notices', function(){
                echo '<p>Greetings from <strong>all_admin_notices</strong>!</p>';
            });

        }
    });
```

Which works in my reservation custom post type. But I'm wondering if it's possible to output content after the title, but before table with custom post types?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to "hijack" the following filter in the `WP_List_Table` class:

```
/**
 * Filter the list of available list table views.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$this->screen->id`, refers
 * to the ID of the current screen, usually a string.
 *
 * @since 3.5.0
 *
 * @param array $views An array of available list table views.
 */
 $views = apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );
```

### Example

For the `edit-post` screen, the filter is `views_edit-post`:

```
/**
 * Display HTML after the 'Posts' title
 * where we target the 'edit-post' screen
 */
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', function( $views )
{
    echo '<p>Greetings from <strong>views_edit-post</strong></p>';

    return $views;
} );
```

and this will display as:

[image: greetings]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with JavaScript.

```
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', function(){
    echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  $( "<p>Greetings from <strong>all_admin_notices</strong>!</p>" ).insertAfter( ".subsubsub" );});</script>';
} );
```

Comment: I was aiming for the non javascript-able solution :\

Comment: Why? Wordpress depends heavily on jQuery and JavaScript. insertAfter is supported by every known browser back to the beginning of time. You would be hard pressed to find a more reliable solution, imho.

Comment: Because, when developing a plugin, I like to do most of the stuf with php (as possible). So if there is a hook to use, why not? :)

Comment: Fair enough. I also prefer to get things done on the server side.

Comment: And.. there clearly is not a hook, looking at the accepted answer - this is a reliable hack!